# Missing required parameter for [Route: Oeuvre.update]

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

My update function in the resource controller

```
public function update(UpdateOeuvreRequest $request, Oeuvre $oeuvre)
    {
     
        $oeuvre->titre = $request->input('titre');
        $oeuvre->auteur = $request->input('auteur');
        $oeuvre->annee = $request->input('annee');
        $oeuvre->description = $request->input('description');
        $oeuvre->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
        $oeuvre->qt = $request->input('qt');
        $query=$oeuvre->save();
        if($query){
        return redirect()->route('Oeuvre')->with('success','updated successfuly');

        }
    }
```

MY edit.blade.php

```
<form  action="{{ route('Oeuvre.update',$oeuvre) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
@csrf
@method('PUT')
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3 mb-md-0">
            <input class="form-control" value="{{$oeuvre->titre}}" name="titre" type="text" placeholder="titre" />
            
            <label for="titre">Titre</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input class="form-control" value="{{$oeuvre->auteur}}" name="auteur" type="text" placeholder="auteur" />
            <label for="auteur">Auteur</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Something is missing here, the way you use the route in your code example is correct, are you certain you don't use route('Oeuvre.update') anywhere else?

Comment: You need to pass $ourvre as an array key, `route('Oeuvre.update',['oeuvre' => $oeuvre])` - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes

Comment: @aynber it's very forgiving, especially if the route only has a single parameter. The shown syntax is valid, as is your suggestion, and `route('Oeuvre.update',[$oeuvre])`

Comment: @mrhn we have no idea if it's correct, since the route definition is not given, nor any details about the error message. VTC as needing debug info

Comment: @miken32 we know based on the exception screenshot, and route helper can take a single element as the 2. parameter without a problem :)

Comment: @mrhn ah I have images blocked so can't see it. Regardless, VTC is still appropriate given the lack of information.

Comment: Show us your routes please

Answer (score -1):

I think what is happening  is that you are using this parameter in your controller =>
$oeuvre

Then you have to pass it  also through your form and route